# I want get contact from RTC DB in Lync Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, lync, mmc3

I have A project to manage a Contact in Lync Server

When I success to make a Populate Contact List for user, but when the user LogIn in MS Lync client the States tab doesn't work?

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for your interesting,
When i populate the contact list from my tool & When the user login from his Lync client he found all contact in the groups with them status in Groups Tab & he doesn't found them in the Status Tab or Relationship Tab.

What do you think in think? 
Thanks a lot 
Eslam ELMoawen